# How do I prevent a page from hijacking my Pentadactyl navigation keys?

Tags: firefox, facebook, pentadactyl

Facebook wants me to use their own set of keyboard shortcuts for navigating their site, but these don't play that well with my Pentadactyl setup. How can I prevent Facebook from hijacking my keys, so I can use what I'm comfortable with?

Comment: What I want to know is, if there is a way to disable these webby key-board short-cuts from within firefox.

Answer (score 6):

Correct me if I'm misunderstanding something about your question, but by default any shortcuts or key bindings that a website has are disabled by Pentadactyl and only Pentadactyl commands apply.

But an essential "trick" is to switch into pass through mode by typing `<C-z>` (hold down control and type z). This will allow you use the shortcuts and keybindings that the website defined. Then you just hit `<escape>` to go back to normal mode.

A slight variation on this is the `<C-v>` command which will pass only the next key press through to the website.

Comment: I have this problem as well, with vimperator. Sometimes when I alt+tab back to my browser, vimperator's bindings won't "kick-in" right away. If I am on a tab with github, or facebook, for example, their key-board shortcuts will be available to me. In this case, when I go to hit 't' for new tab, I will instead get some garbage I don't want.

Comment: Vimperator strictly speaking was branched long back from Pentadactyl. Therefore I can't comment on that. But what I can tell you is the latest nightly of the pentadactyl works perfectly for Facebook and other browsers. Please make sure you are updated to the latest version. Also the above answer explains the situation perfectly!

Comment: This answer addresses the opposite of what the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Eric Mathison's answer above: You can configure Pentadactyl to remember that you want to use pass-through mode for any specific website using an autocommand. For example, to configure pass-through mode for anything from Facebook's domain, just issue this command:

```
:au LocationChange facebook.com :normal! <C-z>
```

This tells Pentadactyl to enter pass-through mode every time you navigate to any site at facebook.com or switch to a tab in which it is open. To read more about autocommands (and the events you can use to trigger them), type `:help autocommands`; to see examples type `:help autocmd-examples`.